# Inequality in Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Show that $\dfrac{28}{81}<\int_0^\frac{1}{3}e^{x^2}dx<\dfrac{3}{8}$.

It would be great if a solution based on the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals is posted.

Answer (score 1):

Over $[0,1]$, we have:
$$ e^{x^2} = 1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+\theta\cdot x^6,\qquad \theta\in\left[\frac{1}{6},e-\frac{5}{2}\right]\subset\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$0\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{x^2}\,dx - \left( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{81}+\frac{1}{2430}\right)\leq\frac{1}{60000}.$$
This gives:
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{x^2}\,dx \approx\color{red}{\frac{841}{2430}}=\color{blue}{0.346\ldots} $$

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstand. But, are you actually estimating an approximate value of the integral and thus proving that this approximate value lies between $28/81$ and $3/8$?

Comment: @AranyaDey: yes, I proved that the value of the integral is at most $\frac{1}{60000}$ apart from $\frac{841}{2430}$, hence it lies for sure in the given interval $\left[\frac{28}{81},\frac{3}{8}\right].$

Comment: Pretty darn beautiful! +1

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the upper bound, note that for $|x| < 1$

$$e^{x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!} < \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k} = \frac1{1-x^2}.$$

Hence,

$$\int_0^{1/3}e^{x^2}\,dx < \int_0^{1/3}\frac{dx}{1-x^2} <  \frac1{3}\frac{1}{1-(1/3)^2}= \frac1{3}\frac{9}{8}= \frac{3}{8}.$$

The lower bound is easily derived by truncating the Taylor series.

Comment: After "Hence,", you used to Mean Value Theorem for Integrals after the 2nd inequality. Am I correct?

Comment: @Aranya Dey:  I just used the upper bound for $1/(1-x^2)$ on $[0,1/3]$ and $f(x) < 9/8 \implies \int_0^{1/3}f(x)dx < (1/3)(9/8)$

Comment: Actually, you used the Mean Value Theorem and applied an inequality. Anyway, thanks !!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: BTW for Power Series expansion of $e$ you need not take $|x|<1$. In fact, the radius of convergence of $e$ is whole $\mathbb R$

Comment: Sure, but you need $|x| < 1$ for the geometric series on the RHS to converge to $1/(1-x^2)$.

Comment: Oh yes, that is right. Sorry for overlooking.